Installation of “pyenv”, “pyenv-virtualenv” and “pyenv-virtualenvwrapper” on a MacBook with M1 processor
this is the first time I'm asking a question on Stack Overflow and I apologize in advance for any mistakes.
On my work PC (Windows) I use the virtualenvwrapper to create virtual environments for my Python projects. As I find working with the virtualenvwrapper very practical, I would also like to use it on my MacBook with M1 processor. When installing the virtualenvwrapper on my MacBook, I came across pyenv and pyenv-virtualenv. Due to the advertised advantages of these two extensions, I had made up my mind to install pyenv, pyenv-virtualenv and pyenv-virtualenvwrapper. However, I have not yet managed to get all three extensions to work together. I have set the environment variables in .zprofile as follows.
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH"
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
[[ -d $PYENV_ROOT/bin ]] && export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
export PYENV_VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PREFER_PYVENV="true"

Unfortunately, the articles I have found on this topic so far have not been able to help me either, which is probably due to my lack of specialist knowledge. I have therefore decided to actively ask two questions. Many thanks in advance for your help.

Does it make sense or is it even possible to use the three extensions together?
If so, what is the correct procedure to install and run all three extensions?

